# What iOS view to choose for laying out several buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm new to iOS devel so I'm sorry if this is a simple question.

I have a scrollView in an iPad application, inside that scrollview I was inserting several UIButtons. This scrollview displays my buttons (that have a UIImage for background) in a vertical way, allowing me to scroll when the amount of buttons don't fit on the layout.

However my goal is a little different, I wish to click any of the buttons, and when any button is clicked, a new group of UIButtons (with UIImages on their background) should appear right after the clicked button, also inside the scrollView. When I click another button, the previously opened set of buttons "closes", and now a new set opens beneath the clicked button.

I'm not 100% familiar with all the building blocks in iOS applications, could anyone suggest what views would best serv this purpose?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code you're working with..?

Comment: Hello @Drewness, I don't have much code to show, I have a simple UIScrollView and then I programmatically create the UIButtons and add them the the scrollView with addSubview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would almost certainly choose `UICollectionView` to arrange a set of buttons on the screen. When the user performs an action that requires a new set of buttons, you only need to update the set of data being presented by the collection view and call the `reloadData` method.

To clarify how you can use UICollectionView in your specific case, you should have a view controller class which has a reference to a UICollectionView as well as the buttons that you wish to display. This class can have an NSArray or NSMutableArray which contains the buttons, e.g.

```
@property (readwrite, strong) NSMutableArray *buttons;
```

You initially populate the `buttons` array with instances of `UIButton` which you will display in the collection view. When you implement the `UICollectionView` data source method to return a cell for index path, you get the buttons from this array.

Then, a user action happens and you need to display a different set of buttons. So you empty the `buttons` array and put the new `UIButton` instances here. Then you call, for example, `[self.collectionView reloadData];` and then the new cells are created and associated with your new buttons.

Comment: So, I would create a UICollectionView, the first data set only has my main buttons, when I click one of them I reload the data set with all the main buttons, plus the ones that belong to the group I just opened right? Won't this make the UICollectionView itens move, or reset the scroll? I'll try that anyhow! Thank you

Comment: @circuit I expanded an answer to provide a more detailed approach to your situation. Does this sound like what you want?

Comment: Hello, I tried this and it works fine, no problems... thank you!